# Set random background colors on random timer

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to set random background colors using a forEach loop, but all the divs are getting the same background color with the same timer.

Here's the link to the codepen. https://codepen.io/McKern/pen/gvoZRp

```
var bgColors = [
        "#260CE8",
        "#7D1AFF",
        "#A90CE0",
        "#385EFF",
        "#0F0559",
        "#FF37EB"
    ];

    $('.box').each(function(){
        timer = setInterval( function() {
            randomBgColor = bgColors[Math.floor(Math.random() * bgColors.length)];
            randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((25-10)+1) + 10);
            box = $('.box');
            $('.box').css('backgroundColor', randomBgColor)
        }, 1000);
    });
```

Comment: Swap `$('.box').css('backgroundColor', randomBgColor)` for `$(this).css('backgroundColor', randomBgColor)`

Comment: `$('.box')` selects _all_ the box elements, so `$('.box').css` changes the colour on all of them. NewToJs is right, using `this` instead will select the current item in the each loop

Comment: Here is a [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/z1w65a5u/) I have also moved the interval outside of the loop.

Comment: Instead of all the background colors changing in unison, they don't change at all

Comment: That works. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the value from the [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

and change the first and 3 from last line in your pen.

```
$('.box').each(function(i, l){
  timer = setInterval( function() {
    randomBgColor = bgColors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 
bgColors.length)];
    randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((25-10)+1) + 10);
    box = $('.box');
    $(l).css('backgroundColor', randomBgColor)
  }, 1000);
});
```